# Sharing a whatsapp link via sms

Tags: android, html, whatsapp

I would like to send text message that will have a link to share on whatsapp.

I know the "whatsapp://send?text=My Message" protocol. but this must be triggered from a browser.

What I would like to have is a bit.ly link that I send via text (sms), that people can actually click on it and be directed to web and then redirected to whatsapp contacts screen.

Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: sounds like its not possible till now its the system functionality of sms app of android system

Comment: Are you sure about that ?

Comment: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251